# starting Django shell but python interpreter kicks off

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ubuntu-20.04, django-shell

I started the Django's shell using:

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

but weirdly the python interpreter is kicking off instead (I see >>> instead of [n]:, and the initializing text contains no Django information, besides the main imports for the shell aren't executed)

considering that: I'm in ubuntu 20.04, It was running with no problem with python instead of python3, now python isn't recognized but it's linked to python3 so no difference "isn't it??!".

Comment: make sure you still have ipython installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problems can appear if you're using global python installation instead of virtual enviroments. It's better to create a virtual enviroment.

```
sudo apt install -y python3-venv
```

Then cd to your project directory and execute:

```
python3 -m venv env
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then install your requirements and start django shell as usual, by executing

```
python manage.py shell
```

Comment: Nice, so mark my answer as correct, please :)
Be advised: now every time you open up your project directory, you need to execute "source venv/bin/activate" before opening shell or running a server. If youre activated venv correctly, there will be "(venv)" at the left of your username in terminal

Comment: yes it worked perfectly sorry I forget to check the answer